# Should the logout route be protected?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-middleware, laravel-sanctum

I'm making an API with Laravel using Sanctum for authentication, and I having a error when I put the logout route inside auth:sanctum middleware, like this:

[image]

But when I put this route outside the middleware it works...

The easiest way is leaving the route outside, but can u recommend me what is the best practice for this situations?

Comment: There's no reason to need to restrict access to the logout route.

Comment: Is not necessary protect the routes that only a authenticated user can use? For example a logout route, I think. If its unnecessary then its okay to leave outside the auth:sanctum middleware route group

Comment: What happens when an unauthenticated user logs out?

Comment: The subtly here is that asking people to login to logout is a ridiculous notion.